# how to display listview's scroll item by item

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

i want to display the listview's scroll item by item, means single item height is equal to listview height, so on listview there is only one item will display at a time, and after scrolling the listview, remaining item will display. But problem is that if i scroll listview, it scroll many items, but i need to scroll only by one item.

in-short listview scroll by many row at a time but i want only one row scroll at a time

please suggest me some tips or method :)
thank you

Comment: Do you need it to scroll vertically? If not why not use a Gallery instead of a ListView ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html )?

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly, you want a 'pager', sort of like, you scroll page per page instead of inbetween every item, right?

I'm using a Horizontal Pager at the moment, it uses a GroupView and measures the scroll amount to snap to the next view in the pager. Perhaps you could write your own GroupView as well calculating the scroll Y values to snap to the next page..
It's not going to be easy, but it's the only way I can think of.

You could look up Horizontal Pager on google and look at the code, and implement it for vertical paging :)